# Input not supported error in monitor after overclocking the processor

Tags: display, cpu, amd-radeon, overclocking

Hi please any help would be appreciated. 
Here is my PC specs

> AMD A4-4000, 4GB DDR-3 RAM, windows 8.1+ubuntu 14.04

My trouble started when i tried to overclock my processor by using the gigabyte ET 6 application. After i overclocked the processor the system asked for a reboot and after that Iam getting a black screen with a message

> Input not supported

I cant even get to the bios screen.
Will connecting another monitor with higher resolution solve the issue.  Iam currently using

> Acer P166HQL monitor

Thanks....

Comment: Have you tried just turning the monitor on and off a few times? This randomly happens to me occasionally and I just turn the monitor on and off a couple times and then it works again.

Comment: @Probst Yes i tried doing that. But not fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys i solved the isssue. As i mentioned in the question i tried connecting a monitor with a higher resolution and it worked.Then changed the overclocking configs in the bios and thats it. It works perfectly now.